# PHP/MYSQL Add batch of records

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file, insert

I want to add a bunch of people to a table at the same time.  Is there a way to do a batch insert perhaps as an array or do I need to use a loop as in for each...`mysql_query(Insert into people (name,address,email) values ('$name','$adr','$email'))`.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format :

`"INSERT INTO table (id,value) VALUES (1,'temp1'),(2,'temp2'),(3,'temp3')"`

So as per your query:

```
mysql_query("insert into people (name,address,email) 
values ('$name1','$adr1','$email1'),
values ('$name2','$adr2','$email2'),
values ('$name3','$adr3','$email3'),
values ('$name4','$adr4','$email4')
");
```

Comment: Please remember to use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape to make sure you are secure against SQL Injection. And even better use, prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO people (name, address,email)
       VALUES ('$name','$adr','$email'),
              ('$name2','$adr2','$email2'),
              ('$name3','$adr3','$email3')
```

As for the implementation of the query, I'd go away from the `mysql_` functions since the docs clearly state that for newer versions of MySql which you are likely to be using, you should use `mysqli` instead.

> If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly
>   recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead.

[The manual for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Sample of usage:

```
mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo $mysqli->connect_error;
}else{
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO people (name, address,email)
                    VALUES ('$name','$adr','$email'),
                           ('$name2','$adr2','$email2'),
                           ('$name3','$adr3','$email3')");
}
```